# I'd like to fully grasp Linux to make the most out of it

Tags: 14.04, ssh, filesystem, vpn

I have a basic idea of how to fix basic stuff like update issues, how to nano a file spotted with cd and ls in terminal, etc. but I would like to thoroughly learn the File System and how to explore and modify it from within Terminals/Konsoles/etc.

I am particularly interested in all aspects of Networking and want to learn about ssh, setting VPN, proxies, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are many websites that provide information on this, here's two that I initially found:

- http://linuxsurvival.com/
- http://psychocats.net/ubuntu/

If there is something specific you want to learn, just look it up. IE, want to know how to setup ssh on your system? Look up (Google) "How to setup SSH on Ubuntu". The first result is a really good resource:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring

Anything on [help.ubuntu.com](http://help.ubuntu.com) is going to be really useful for you. It may be documentation, which is difficult to read or boring, but it is full and indepth.

Its not that hard to find information on Ubuntu. Just look around, browse questions on here. If what they are talking about interests you, look up how to do it on Google, and you'll find good information on it.

With Ubuntu being open-source and so community-focused, it is really easy to find out how to do things, because chances are, someone else has already done it on their system.